# Change query parameters and return the url

Tags: php

I have the following method:

```
public static function replaceSlug($name, $value)
{
   $fullUrl = self :: getFullUrl();
   $queryString = parseUrl($fullUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY);   

   $slugs = array();
   parse_str($queryString, $slugs);

   foreach ($slugs as &$slug) {
      if ($slug == $name) {
         if ($value == null) {
            unset($slug);
         } else {
            $slug = $value;
         }
      }
   }

   return ''; // what to return?
}
```

I call it with two parameters - the name of the query parameter to change, and the value that it will be changed to. If this value is null, I want to remove this query parameter.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just rebuild the query string with [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and return the string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know what to return although the title of your question is:

> Change query parameters and **return the url**

So if you want to return the URL just do:

```
return $fullUrl . '?' . http_build_query($slugs);
```

If, of course, `$fullUrl` stores the URL host and path without the query string (that you would manually append).

Comment: Isn't $fullUrl filled with old query sting?

Comment: It's indeed most likely but I do not know the OP's function `parseUrl()` and what is the second argument to retrieve only the host/path without the query string.

Comment: That makes sense. Just because i think it is what it should be, it may actually be something totally different. ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebuild the parameters from $slugs array:

```
$res = "";
foreach($slugs as $slug)
    $res .= $slug . "&";
$res = substr($res, -1); /// removes the last &
...
//concatenate $res with the other parts of your URL getting them from your 
//parseUrl function, i.e., the http, host, and path parts from url except the 
//PHP_URL_QUERY part. This has already came from the code above.
...
return $res
```

Comment: Any specific reason to **not** use `http_build_query()` function?

Comment: Yes. And that's the best specific reason in the world: I didn't knew that function :D

Comment: I would edit my answer to include it, but it feels like I'd be cheating. Please post your own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the array so `foreach` is not operating on a copy of the array.

[*foreach*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Then rebuild your query with `http_build_query`.

[*http_build_query*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

```
<?php
function replaceSlug($name, $value)
{
    //$fullUrl = self :: getFullUrl();
    //$queryString = parseUrl($fullUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY);  
    
    // just faking the query str here. Put the above back in
    // and delete this one.
    $queryString = "foo=bar&baz=boo&boogaloo=";
    
    $slugs = array();
    parse_str($queryString, $slugs);
    
    foreach ($slugs as $n => & $v) {
        if ($n == $name ) {
            if (strlen($slugs[$n]) == 0) {
                unset($slugs[$n]);
            } else {
                $slugs[$n] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    $splitUri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
    
    return 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $splitUri[0] 
        . "?" . http_build_query($slugs); // returns full url with a new query string
}

$result = replaceSlug('foo', 'oof');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
$result = replaceSlug('boogaloo', 'oolagoob');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```